# How to get the compression ratio for a GZipped file?

Tags: java, jsp, zip

Here is how I compressed the data:

```
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.jsp.*,java.io.*,java.util.zip.*" %>

<%
String encodings = request.getHeader("Accept-Encoding");
PrintWriter outWriter = null;

if ((encodings != null) && (encodings.indexOf("gzip") != -1)) {
  OutputStream outA = response.getOutputStream();
  outWriter = new PrintWriter(new GZIPOutputStream(outA), false);
  response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
  int a = response.getBufferSize();
  System.out.println("ZIPPED VERSION BF:"+a);
} 
else {
  System.out.println("UN-ZIPPED VERSION");
  outWriter = new PrintWriter(response.getOutputStream(), false);
}

outWriter.println("<HTML><BODY>");

for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
  outWriter.println(" blah blah blah<br>");
}

outWriter.println("</BODY></HTML>");
outWriter.close();
%>
```

Comment: It's going to compress insanely well in your test, due to the large quantities of repeated text.  You may want to consider using the actual content of a few of your larger pages to better test how compression will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to sound harsh, but this approach is totally wrong. First, you don't want to do this in a JSP file due to at least two reasons: 1) raw Java code (*scriptlets*) belongs in real Java classes and 2) JSP is for character data, not for binary data, it would only corrupt the data. Second, any decent appserver provides a configuration option whether to automatically GZIP the response or not. In for example [Tomcat 6.0](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html), you can just extend the `<Connector>` element in `/conf/server.xml` with a `compression` attribute which is set to `"on"`:

```
<Connector ... compression="on" />
```

Also see [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/09/webapplication-performance-tips-and.html) for more hints with regard to webapp performance.

Back to your actual question: there's no setting to alter the compression ratio for GZIP. It's also not needed.

**Update**: I realized that you asked *get*, not *set*. Well, use a HTTP client and calculate the length of the `InputStream`. Here's a basic kickoff example with help of [`java.net.URLConnection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html):

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://localhost/context/page.jsp");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"); // Outcomment this to turn off GZIP.
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
for (int data = 0; (data = input.read()) != -1; output.write(data));
System.out.println("Length: " + output.toByteArray().length + " bytes");
```

Then just do the primary school math to get the compression ratio. Divide, multiply, etc ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something here you just manually calculate original size divided by compressed size.